# How can I load gMod maps in CS1.6?

Tags: counter-strike, garrys-mod

If is that possible, how can I load gMod maps in CS1.6? I tried to start HLDS with that GM map and I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source games use a significantly newer version of BSP than GoldSrc does.

You *might* be able to open a Garry's Mod map in Counter-Strike: Source due to it using a similar game engine, but not in Counter-Strike 1.6.

Comment: So there will be no conversion to CS16? Ok, thanks anyway.

Comment: Just like you cant play csgo, l4d2, portal 2, stanley parable, etc. game maps on gmod due to those games being newer source engines, but you _can_ play css, gmod, etc. games on newer source engine games if you mess around with the console to run the maps properly.